# No access to global variable after bundle with webpack

Tags: webpack, global-variables, bundle

In my main app.js I have a bunch of classes and things.
After everything, I simply create a global variable so I can access it trough the console and the index.html

```
Long typescript code..classes, interfaces, etc.

var Obj= new ObjectClass();
```

If I don't use webpack at all, Obj is accessible via console and in the index.html.
When it goes trough the bundle process, I just lose this access and so does the index.html
I know that webpack does something with the scope of those variables. But how can I expose it? I really need it.

Comment: `window.obj = new ObjectClass();`?

Comment: For typescript I guess that (<any> window).obj=  new ObjectClass(); is the solution.
But what about simple global variables? 
Variables that I use along the typescript file